# retrieve the real domain owner

Tags: domain, whois, owner

is there anyway to retrieve the real domain owner to contact them/him/her to start a bid with ?

Cause if i use whois.net site it sends me to resellers sites then resellers send me to other sites then to other sites, really unbelievable.

thanks

Comment: domain i'm searching for is a .com

Answer (score 2):

WHOIS will contain information, if WHOIS contains reseller information that means domain belongs to them and you can only work with them to get it.

Comment: ok so i need to contact them right?

Comment: right, as of this very moment domains belongs to them and they're the only one who can release it to you, so you have no other choice but to go through them.